# Roll Over Images not Functioning in one Column

Tags: responsive, rollover, rollovers

http://jenellehamilton.com/

Under the clients section - the bottom 2 left most logos will not roll over. But same script, in a different position in the grid will function.

I've been racking my brain. Is it the responsive layout?
This is the Beginning java that calls it. I've also set to preload all of the images.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function MM_swapImgRestore() { //v3.0
  var i,x,a=document.MM_sr; for(i=0;a&&i<a.length&&(x=a[i])&&x.oSrc;i++) x.src=x.oSrc;
}
function MM_preloadImages() { //v3.0
  var d=document; if(d.images){ if(!d.MM_p) d.MM_p=new Array();
    var i,j=d.MM_p.length,a=MM_preloadImages.arguments; for(i=0; i<a.length; i++)
    if (a[i].indexOf("#")!=0){ d.MM_p[j]=new Image; d.MM_p[j++].src=a[i];}}
}

function MM_findObj(n, d) { //v4.01
  var p,i,x;  if(!d) d=document; if((p=n.indexOf("?"))>0&&parent.frames.length) {
    d=parent.frames[n.substring(p+1)].document; n=n.substring(0,p);}
  if(!(x=d[n])&&d.all) x=d.all[n]; for (i=0;!x&&i<d.forms.length;i++) x=d.forms[i][n];
  for(i=0;!x&&d.layers&&i<d.layers.length;i++) x=MM_findObj(n,d.layers[i].document);
  if(!x && d.getElementById) x=d.getElementById(n); return x;
}

function MM_swapImage() { //v3.0
  var i,j=0,x,a=MM_swapImage.arguments; document.MM_sr=new Array; for(i=0;i<(a.length-2);i+=3)
   if ((x=MM_findObj(a[i]))!=null){document.MM_sr[j++]=x; if(!x.oSrc) x.oSrc=x.src; x.src=a[i+2];}
}
        </script>
```

This section is the HTML Grid. The last 2 rows first image doesn't swap. I've tested in Google and there are no 'errors' of missing links to images...

```
<!-- Clients -->
    <section class="section-wrap clients bg-light" id="clients">
        <div class="container"> 

                  <div class="row heading">

                        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
                            <h2 class="text-center bottom-line"><b>Clients</b></h2>

                      </div>
                  </div>
                    <div class="row" >
                         <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3" style="padding-bottom:20px;">
                            <center>
                                <a href="http://www.at60inches.com/" onMouseOver="MM_swapImage('@60','','img/C-60-over.png',1)" onMouseOut="MM_swapImgRestore()"><img src="img/C-60-up.png" width="150px" alt="@60" id="@60"></a>
                            </center>
                         </div>
                         <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3" style="padding-bottom:20px;">
                            <center>
                                <a href="http://andrewalkerhair.com/" onMouseOut="MM_swapImgRestore()" onMouseOver="MM_swapImage('Andre Walker','','img/C-ANDRE-over.png',1)"><img src="img/C-ANDRE-UP.png" alt="Andre Walker Hair" width="150px" id="Andre Walker"></a>
                            </center>
                         </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3" style="padding-bottom:20px;">
                            <center>
                                <a href="https://www.domainecarneros.com/" onMouseOut="MM_swapImgRestore()" onMouseOver="MM_swapImage('Domaine Carneros','','img/C-domaie-over.png',1)"><img src="img/C-domaine-up.png" alt="Domaine Carneros by Taittinger"  width="150px" id="Domaine Carneros"></a>
                            </center>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3" style="padding-bottom:20px;">
                            <center>
                                <a href="http://www.tomford.com/" onMouseOut="MM_swapImgRestore()" onMouseOver="MM_swapImage('Tom Ford','','img/C-ford-over.png',1)"><img src="img/C-ford-UP.png" alt="Tom Ford" width="150px" id="Tom Ford"></a>
                            </center>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3" style="padding-bottom:20px;">
                            <center>
                                <a href="http://goodwillnynj.org/about-us" onMouseOut="MM_swapImgRestore()" onMouseOver="MM_swapImage('Goodwill','','img/C-Goodwill-over.png',1)"><img src="img/C-Goodwill-up.png" alt="Goodwill NYNJ" width="150px" id="Goodwill"></a>
                            </center>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3" style="padding-bottom:20px;">
                            <center>
                                <a href="http://simplygum.com/" onMouseOut="MM_swapImgRestore()" onMouseOver="MM_swapImage('Simply Gum','','img/C-gum-over.png',1)"><img src="img/C-gum-UP.png" alt="Simply Gum" width="150px" id="Simply Gum"></a>
                            </center>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3" style="padding-bottom:20px;">
                            <center> 
                                <a href="http://www.hearst.com/about" onMouseOut="MM_swapImgRestore()" onMouseOver="MM_swapImage('Hearst','','img/C-hearst-over.png',1)"><img src="img/C-hearst-up.png" alt="Hearst" width="150" id="Hearst"></a>
                            </center> 
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3" style="padding-bottom:20px;">
                            <center>
                                <a href="http://bobmackie.com/pages/bobs-bio" onMouseOut="MM_swapImgRestore()" onMouseOver="MM_swapImage('Bob Mackie','','img/C-mackie-over.png',1)"><img src="img/C-mackie-up.png" alt="Bob Mackie" width="150" id="Bob Mackie"></a> 
                            </center>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                         <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3" style="padding-bottom:20px;">
                             <center>
                                <a href="http://erstwhilejewelry.com/" onMouseOut="MM_swapImgRestore()" onMouseOver="MM_swapImage('Erstwell','','img/C-erstwell-over.png',1)"><img src="img/C-erstwell-up.png" alt="Erstwell Jewelry" width="200" id="Erstwell"></a>
                            </center>
                         </div>
                         <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3" style="padding-bottom:20px;">
                            <center>
                                <a href="http://www.taittinger.fr/" onMouseOut="MM_swapImgRestore()" onMouseOver="MM_swapImage('Taittinger','','img/C-Taittinger-over.png',1)"><img src="img/C-Taittinger-UP.png" alt="Taittinger" width="150" id="Taittinger"></a>
                            </center>
                         </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3" style="padding-bottom:20px;">
                            <center>
                                <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PRzh7hhsk84" onMouseOut="MM_swapImgRestore()" onMouseOver="MM_swapImage('WIE Network','','img/C-wie-over.png',1)"><img src="img/C-wie-up.png" alt="WIE Network" width="150" id="WIE Network"></a>
                            </center>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3" style="padding-bottom:20px;">
                            <center>
                                <a href="http://candicekumai.com/about" onMouseOut="MM_swapImgRestore()" onMouseOver="MM_swapImage('Candice','','img/C-candice-over.png',1)"><img src="img/C-candice-up.png" alt="Candice Kumai" width="150" id="Candice"></a>
                            </center>
                        </div>
                  </div>
                 <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3" style="padding-bottom:20px;">
                        <center>
                          <a href="https://www.delivery.com/info/about" onMouseOut="MM_swapImgRestore()" onMouseOver="MM_swapImage('com','','img/C-Delivery-over.png',1)">
                          <img src="img/C-Delivery-up.png" alt="Delivery.com" width="150" id="Delivery.com"></a>
                        </center>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3" style="padding-bottom:20px;">
                        <center>
                          <a href="http://kettlebellkickboxing.com/" onMouseOut="MM_swapImgRestore()" onMouseOver="MM_swapImage('Kettlebell Kickboxing','','img/C-kettle-over.png',1)"><img src="img/C-kettle-UP.png" alt="Kettlebell Kickboxing" width="150" id="Kettlebell Kickboxing"></a>
                        </center>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3" style="padding-bottom:20px;">
                        <center>
                          <a href="http://www.nelsonvercher.com/" onMouseOut="MM_swapImgRestore()" onMouseOver="MM_swapImage('Nelson','','img/C-nelson-over.png',1)"><img src="img/C-nelson-up.png" alt="Nelson Verner" width="150" id="Nelson"></a>
                        </center>
                    </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3" style="padding-bottom:20px;">
                        <center>
                            <a href="https://www.mentedcosmetics.com/" onMouseOut="MM_swapImgRestore()" onMouseOver="MM_swapImage('Mented','','img/C-Mented-over.png',1)"><img src="img/C-Mented-up.png" alt="Mented" width="150" id="Mented"></a>   
                        </center>
                    </div>

                </div>
                <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3">
                            <center>
                                <a href="http://shortyawards.com/socialgood" onMouseOut="MM_swapImgRestore()" onMouseOver="MM_swapImage('Shorty Social Good Awards','','img/C-ShortyGood-over.png',1)"><img src="img/C-ShortyGood-up.png" alt="Shorty Social Good Awards" width="150" id="Shorty Social Good"></a>
                            </center>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3">
                            <center>
                                <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=1&v=lIKzgXJxBU8" onMouseOut="MM_swapImgRestore()" onMouseOver="MM_swapImage('Shorty Awards','','img/C-shorty-over.png',1)"><img src="img/C-shorty-up.png" alt="Shorty Awards" width="150" id="Shorty Awards"></a>
                            </center>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3">
                            <center>
                                <a href="http://waxclub.nyc/" onMouseOut="MM_swapImgRestore()" onMouseOver="MM_swapImage('Wax Club','','img/C-WaxClub-over.png',1)"><img src="img/C-WaxClub-up.png" alt="Wax Club" width="150" id="Wax Club"></a>
                            </center>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3"></div>
                </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Please provide snippets of the code and what you think might be causing the issue.   Stack Overflow is a community to help you with your specific programming problem.

Comment: Sorry, I was unable to post this until now.